# Finding sum of terms in a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, arithmetic

> A sequence has $a_1=-2$ and $a_2=4$ and in the sequence, when $n>2$, $a_{n}$= $\dfrac {a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}$. Find the sum of the first $99$ terms of sequence.

I tried to deduce from the patterns produced but couldn't draw any fruitful conclusions. $a_3=-2$, $a_4=-0.5$, $a_5=0.25$ and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every 6 terms are recurring, thus add first 6 terms and then the sum of first 99 terms is 
(16x6)+Sum of three terms

Seems -12 is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

We have that

$$a_{n}= \frac {a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}=\frac {a_{n-2}}{a_{n-3}}\frac {1}{a_{n-2}}=\frac {1}{a_{n-3}}=\ldots=a_{n-6}$$

Comment: so how would I deduce the sums?

Comment: Take another step, what can we deduce? If $a_n=1/a_{n-3}$ what is $a_{n-3}$ equal to?

Comment: I am feeling like a dork man

Comment: @CreamPie Did you calculate any values beyond $a_5$?

Comment: @Théophile yeah just thought it wouldn't matter to you guys

Comment: It easy to obtain that $a_n=a_{n-6}$ that is the sequence is periodic!

Comment: @gimusi I see a little bit ,but could you please wrap it up and provide me a solution that would mean a lot to me

Comment: You are almost near, you don’t need more help than that. Take the pleasure to find it by your own.

Answer (score 1):

If you compute the first $8$ terms, it will be evident that the sequence repeats in blocks of length $6$.

Summing the first $6$ terms, and then multiplying by $16$ yields the sum of the first $96$ terms.

To finish, add the three remaining terms (which are the same as the first three terms).

Comment: It’s not a good idea in my opinion give full solution while the asker is trying to find it with some effort, you could just give the first part as a hint.

Comment: I made a judgement that in this case, more was needed. And also less (more pattern based, less symbolic).

Comment: @gimusi I am a 13 and half year boy getting efforts on higher maths  ,gimusi and quasi I am on debt of you guys

Comment: @quasi can you recommend a book for me to study these things?

Comment: @gimusi can you recommend a book for me to study these things?

Comment: @CreamPie: Try this one: Patrick -- Intermediate Counting and Probability (2007). It's a great book, with lots of challenging problems.

Comment: If you want learn you need to make some effort by your own otherwise you’ll never be able to solve problem by your own. You were really near to the solution but your way to require a full solution without try any effort was very very bad in my opinion for your mental growth and attitude to get skilled in problem solving! You have just lost a good chance in my opinion.

Comment: @gimusi I'll note your opinion ,but my mind was about to explode